# Why rails can't find my sweepers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sweeper

I have on my controller:

```
class FormulariosController < ApplicationController
    cache_sweeper :campanha_sweeper, :only => [:show]

    # actions
end
```

I've tried to create a directory called /sweepers inside app and it didn't work, I've tried inside models to create a /cache folder(there were a blog using this as example) and it didn't work.

My sweeper looks like this:

```
class CampanhaSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Campanha

  def after_update(campanha)
    expire_cache_for(campanha)
  end

  private
  def expire_cache_for(campanha)
    expire_page(:controller => 'formularios', :action => 'show')

    ap "Expired cache for formularios#show in formulariosweeper"
  end
```

end

I get when trying to start the server the following:

```
/Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.12/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:41:in `const_get': uninitialized constant CampanhaSweeper (NameError)
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.12/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:41:in `block in cache_sweeper'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.12/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:39:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.12/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:39:in `cache_sweeper'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/app/controllers/formularios_controller.rb:2:in `<class:FormulariosController>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/app/controllers/formularios_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/Projects-ginga/ginga-campanhas/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/thiagomassa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Why didn't it work? Also, is there any way to expire cache of only a view(of how it's rendered). I'm generating views on the fly and it would be very useful if I could expire the cache of a view that is located at say, views/formularios/a.html.rb

If guys want to know what I'm doing, it's simple. I generate views with forms and when I want to update that view(or it's code) and I'm in production, the view doesn't get updated due to caching so I have to manually reset it's cache everytime I "update" a form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the `sweepers` directory (or where ever you've put the sweeper code) to your `autoload_paths` in `application.rb`?

Comment: If `application.rb`, you should find a line that adds to `config.autoload_paths`. It should end up looking something like `config.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root}/path/to/sweepers )` . There may be other autoload paths already.

Comment: Ok I did that and added `config.active_record.observers = [:order_sweeper]` as well.  I have `cache_sweeper :order_sweeper` in my model and still get an error `uninitialized constant OrderSweeper (NameError)` when I start my server.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Not sure, without seeing it myself, unfortunately :( Is it inheriting from `ActionController::Caching::Sweeper`?